# Remove particular file from dockerignore depending on environment variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `.dockerignore` file which ignores an entire folder, say `folder/`. If I want to retain some file inside that folder, I add another line in my`.dockerignore` which goes like `!folder/some-file-name.ext`.

Now, if this filename were to change, I would have to go and manually change the `.dockerignore` file every time. Is there some way to automate this?

As an example, if I could specify some environment variable, say something like `FILENAME=folder/some-other-file.ext`, and there was some way to have in the `.dockerignore` a line like `!$FILENAME`, then that would solve my problem.

Comment: you can write a wrapper bash script to achieve that easily

Comment: I would try to eliminate the need for solving this problem, rather than solving it. Either avoid mixing ignored and non-ignored files in the same folder, or ignore by file extension or pattern.